# grep -v with while read line command not working properly

Tags: linux, while-loop, grep, command

I use this **command**

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do grep -v "$line" target.txt > tmp; mv tmp target.txt; done < removefrom.txt
```

to remove lines from (**target.txt**) that match string in (**removefrom.txt**)

---

This is (target.txt)

```
e
1
k
2
a
```

This is (removefrom.txt)

```
d
e
c
a
k
b
e
a
```

This is the result should look like:

```
1
2
```

---

But sometimes the resule is like:

```
e
1
2
```

or

```
e
1
2
a
```

or

```
1
2
a
```

---

I ever try to use `sed`, but the problem is still there, It didn't remove lines properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep -vf removefrom.txt target.txt